# Test Polly retry polly configured via Startup.ConfigureServices() with ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, polly

I want to find out how Polly retry polly configured via Startup.ConfigureServices() can be tested.

**ConfigureServices**

Polly policy is configured within it

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                 services.AddHttpClient<IHttpClientService, HttpClientService>()
                .SetWaitAndRetryPolicy1();     

     }
}
```

Below is the Polly policy:

```
 public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
    {

    public static void SetWaitAndRetryPolicy1(this IHttpClientBuilder clientBuilder)
        {
                             clientBuilder.AddPolicyHandler((service, request) =>
                            HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                                .WaitAndRetryAsync(3,
                                    retryCount => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryCount)),
                onRetry: (outcome, timespan, retryCount, context) =>
                                {
                                    service.GetService<ILog>().Error("Delaying for {delay}ms, then making retry {retry}.",
                                        timespan.TotalMilliseconds, retryCount);
                                }
                            )

                        );        
        }
    }
```

Below is what I tried:

**Integration test**

The Polly policy is configured within the test.

```
  public class RetryPolicyTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

        public RetryPolicyTests(WebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory;
        }

        [Theory]
        [InlineData("http://localhost:1234/api/v1/car/")]
        public async Task Test3(string url)
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(whb =>
                {
                    whb.ConfigureServices((bc, sc) =>
                    {
                        sc.AddOptions();
                        sc.AddHttpClient("test")
                          .SetWaitAndRetryPolicy1();         //Test the Polly policy             
                        sc.BuildServiceProvider();
                    });
                })
                .CreateClient();  //cannot get a named or typed HttpClient

            // Act           
            var body = "{}";
            using (var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            {

                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);



            }

            //Assert: somewhy assert it
        }
    }
}
```

The **problem** is that

I cannot retrieve the `HttpClient` that has been configured with the Polly polly. Because `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()` has no overloads that returns a named or typed `HttpClient`:

Any idea?

Is there a better way to testing it?

ASPS.NET Core API 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify your posted code minimally to obtain the named or typed `HttpClient` configured on HttpClientFactory, build the `IServiceProvider`, obtain the `IHttpClientFactory` and then obtain the configured client from `IHttpClientFactory`.

```
var configuredClient = sc.BuildServiceProvider()
    .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("test");
```

Many people consider the use of `IServiceProvider` like this to be a service-locator anti-pattern in production code; perhaps it is ok here in a test, to pull the specific item you want to unit-test out of the default app configuration.  However, there are also shorter ways for a test to get a sample `HttpClient` configured on HttpClientFactory, without using a full `WebApplicationFactory` (see last part of answer).

---

For a full end-to-end integration test, testing how your app uses the configured policy, using `WebApplicationFactory` to exercise some endpoint of your app like `http://localhost:1234/api/v1/car/`:

You could - within the integration test - use a tool like [Mountebank for .NET](https://github.com/mattherman/MbDotNet) or [HttpClientInterception](https://github.com/justeat/httpclient-interception) to stub out the calls that the configured `HttpClient` makes, so that those calls return errors which you expect the policy to handle.

You could use the ability of `WebHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(...)` to modify the normal startup of your app, to make it easy to assert something to prove the policy was called.  For example, you could configure a mock/fake `ILog` implementation, and assert that the `ILog.Error(...)` call in your `onRetry` delegate takes place.

---

For the shortest-possible, self-contained unit test to test a Polly policy configured on a given `HttpClient` configuration on HttpClientFactory, you could use a code pattern like below.  This only uses IHttpClientFactory and the standard Microsoft DI infrastructure; no web host from ASP.NET.

```
public class HttpClientFactory_Polly_Policy_Test
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Given_a_retry_policy_configured_on_a_named_client_When_call_via_the_named_client_Then_the_policy_is_used()
    {
        // Given / Arrange 
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        bool retryCalled = false;

        HttpStatusCode codeHandledByPolicy = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        const string TestClient = "TestClient";
        services.AddHttpClient(TestClient)
            .AddPolicyHandler(HttpPolicyExtensions.HandleTransientHttpError()
                .RetryAsync(3, onRetry: (_, __) => retryCalled = true))
            .AddHttpMessageHandler(() => new StubDelegatingHandler(codeHandledByPolicy));

        HttpClient configuredClient =
            services
                .BuildServiceProvider()
                .GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                .CreateClient(TestClient);

        // When / Act
        var result = await configuredClient.GetAsync("https://www.doesnotmatterwhatthisis.com/");

        // Then / Assert
        Assert.Equal(codeHandledByPolicy, result.StatusCode);
        Assert.True(retryCalled);
    }

}

public class StubDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly HttpStatusCode stubHttpStatusCode;
    public StubDelegatingHandler(HttpStatusCode stubHttpStatusCode) => this.stubHttpStatusCode = stubHttpStatusCode;
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) => Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(stubHttpStatusCode));
}
```

If the declarations of policies are pulled out to methods (like `SetWaitAndRetryPolicy1()` in your posted code), an approach like above provides a more unit-test-focused way to test them.

Comment: This is a shortened version of a longer post (more information about the end-to-end integration approach particularly), at; https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/555